# openvpn in whonix workstation? gksudo to move files as root?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, permissions, whonix

So I've been trying to setup a vpn in whonix workstation but it is proving somewhat difficult for me. Specific vpn is nord vpn and I was following [their instructions for command line install](https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/) but it fails at step 4 as it cannot download the ca and config files.

I then downloaded them in another system and then put them in whonix workstation. When trying to copy the files into `cd /etc/openvpn` I am unable to do so because I don't have root permissions.

From memory I can use gksudo to operate file manager as root and put the files where they need to be. gksudo isn't a recognised command however so that stopped me again.

I don't really want to wreck my system by tapping around in the commandline too much; is there an easy way to put the files where they need to go??

If I had the network manager in whonix workstation it would also be alot easier but again it is hard to get installed etc.

Answer (score 0):

Install gksudo or use the preinstalled kdesudo.

See https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnels/Introduction